# postgres-xc will not install due to broken packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, postgresql

On a 14.04 installation, postgresql was installed via
`sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`

This installation is meant to be a slave but cannot start up without running pg_resetxlog.  Even though `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/` has pg_resetxlog, the system requires installing 'postgres-xc'.

```
apt-get install postgres-xc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgres-xc : Depends: postgres-xc-client but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

if postgres-xc depends on postgres-xc-client, why is this dependency being ignored?

**Update**
Slave is a VPS.  Was installed creating postgresql via
`sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`
On the master (OS X 10.6.8 with postgre installed via homebrew)

```
psql -c "select pg_start_backup('initial_backup');"
rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* /usr/local/var/postgres/ slave_IP_address:/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/
psql -c "select pg_stop_backup();"
```

The slave then had its recovery.conf file created.  but the startup of the slave `service postgresql start` started choking  pg_log being excluded, that directory was then created.
Then:
`PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record`

Comment: PostgreSQL and postgres-xc are *not the same thing*. You should *never* need to run `pg_resetxlog`; something is already wrong if you do. When you say *"The system requires installing postgres-xc"* what exactly do you mean? What error are you referring to?

Comment: on the slave, when running `service postgresql start` i was generating `FATAL: required WAL directory "pg_xlog" does not exist`. I then created pg_xlog and a nested archive_status directory. and hit `PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record` This implies Postgres can't find a properly WAL under the $PGDATA/pg_xlog/ directory. I was undet the understand  that I needed to `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_resetxlog -f /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main`

Comment: Uhh... how did you create this PostgreSQL install? Perhaps you used `pg_basebackup` without the `-X stream` option, but you failed to set up a `restore_command` to copy archive files? It's still not clear where you got the idea that you needed anything to do with postgres-xc here.

Comment: updated question.  note: although we're not supposed to do this here, I must comment that your contributions are among the most insightful around. Yes postgres-xc is not the same.  I"ve learned that by installing it and now the rest is not there.  Good thing this was a test-case: will destroy and re-build.  But there's a step or two that where I'm certainly off...

Comment: As to your question about how I got to postgres-xc, I was under the undersanding that I needed to `pg_resetxlog` and the system told me postgres-xc needed installing.  But as you initially pointed out, I should never have gotten to that point!

Comment: please report a bug about that to Ubuntu. It's *really bad* if it's telling you that. Serious problem.

Comment: What made you think `pg_resetxlog` was the answer? Whatever article you found needs to be corrected because that's dangerously bad advice. Link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799474/postgresql-error-panic-could-not-locate-a-valid-checkpoint-record.  *Three* answers there suggest pg_resetxlog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You copied the base backup without `pg_xlog` - apparently intentionally.

The only time that's OK is when your master has an `archive_command` in its `postgresql.conf` to archive WAL to some shared location, and the replica has a `restore_command` in its `recovery.conf` that can read the archived WAL. Even then, you must `mkdir` the empty `pg_xlog`.

If you are not using WAL archiving you *must* copy `pg_xlog`, including the WAL segment(s) created *after* the end of `pg_stop_backup`, as explained in the manual.

I strongly suggest you use the newer `pg_basebackup` command to make the copy instead. It is much simpler and easier to get right. Simply enable a `replication` connection from the planned replica's address on the master (in `pg_hba.conf), like you would for streaming replication, then:

```
pg_basebackup -D /path/to/new/data/dir -X stream --write-recovery-conf -h master.server.address ...other connection options...
```

to copy the master's data directory, including all required WAL, to the replica. It even creates a `recovery.conf` for you automatically.

---

`postgres-xc` is **not** the same thing as PostgreSQL. It's a non-compatible fork of an older version of PostgreSQL that adds multi-master clustering. It's a serious bug if Ubuntu ever tells you to install `postgres-xc` to get PostgreSQL tools.

**Never run `pg_resetxlog`**. The only time you should is after a serious database failure, and only then after a full backup; see the entry on [database corruption on the wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption).

Comment: master's pg_hba.conf already has `host    replication     all      slave-ip/32         trust` set up. Sorry if I'm being too exactish... does this translate as such: the three commands shown above to synch the db would be replaced by `pg_basebackup -D slave_IP_address:/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/ -X stream --write-recovery-conf -h /usr/local/var/postgres/ ...other connection options...` alone?  rsynch is taken out of the loop (that would be nice)?

Comment: @Jerome Correct. No `pg_start_backup` / `rsync` / `pg_stop_backup`

Comment: wonderfully succinct!